# Build AVR Studio 4 project in AVR Studio 5

Tags: avr, avr-gcc, winavr, avr-studio4, avr-studio5

I have an AT90USB162 Minimus AVR which I want to integrate into a project. I downloaded [the demo code](http://www.minimususb.com/files/AVR-USB-162-CDC.zip) from [Minimus USB](http://minimususb.com/).  This is a driver for using the AVR as a COM port.  The project is written for AVR Studio 4, and cannot be loaded as-is in AVR Studio 5.

How can I convert the project for use with AVR Studio 5?

Comment: You *might* be having trouble? What trouble, and why aren't you sure whether you're having it or not?

Comment: Corrected. I am having. Thanks.

Comment: I could not build. No idea on how could do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I just got to build the package. The problem is that the original sources were configured to be built in AVR Studio v.4, and mine is v.5, so I had to convert them to my version. So, you can follow the instructions:

1. Unzip the content of the AVR-USB-162-CDC.zip to a folder. Inside it you will see the folder Atmel. Move this folder to c:\Atmel (so you will have c:\Atmel\at90usb162-cdc-1_0_1);
2. In AVR Studio v.5, go to menu File/Import/AVR Studio 4 Project and where you see APS File Location, Browse to c:\Atmel\at90usb162-cdc-1_0_1\at90usb162\demo\cdc\gcc\cdc.aps
3. Click Convert and so Finish and Close.

You can build the project with Build/Build Solution. The .hex will be saved in C:\Atmel\at90usb162-cdc-1_0_1\at90usb162\demo\cdc\gcc\cdc.hex.

I'm yet studying the code due to know the COMPORT parameters. But at least I'm already able to burn the hex into the microchip. If someone know details of this COMPORT please comment.

That's it. I hope it helps other newbies like me.